# How to bring a view back from superview once RemoveFromSuperview() has been used

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating an IOS app that requires me to hide and then show a view. I used RemoveFromSuperview() to make the view disappear however I cannot seem to find a way to bring it back into view.

Comment: `.AddSubview` on the view that you need to add it back to.

Comment: Why not use the `.isHidden` property? It is much simpler than removing or re-adding the view

Comment: I have solved my problem however, .isHidden is no for c# instead anyone who is using c# should use .hidden = true.